# ¿Se debe escribir artículo delante de una palabra extranjera que ya lo contiene en su lengua?

Tags: gramática, artículos, nombres-propios, extranjerismos

Supongamos que estamos hablando del periódico *The Times* o de la banda de música The Rolling Stones.
Como sabemos, *the* es un artículo en inglés, por lo que a efectos prácticos estamos doblando el artículo al usar uno en castellano y otro en lengua extranjera. Tendemos pues a recortar uno y decir:

> <s>Me gusta leer el *The Times*</s>
> Me gusta leer el *Times*
>
> <s>Me gusta escuchar a los *The Rolling Stones*</s>
> Me gusta escuchar a los *Rolling Stones*

Pero supongamos que hablamos del periódico de los Países Bajos *Het Parool*. En neerlandés, *het* es un artículo, pero no tenemos por qué saberlo. Entonces, no sonaría demasiado mal decir:

> Me gusta leer el *Het Parool*

ya que hacer lo mismo que con los Rolling sonaría muy raro, pues *Parool* a secas no resulta completo como nombre del periódico:

> Me gusta leer el *Parool*

Más complicado sería cuando el artículo pertenece a lenguas no tan conocidas en nuestro ámbito, como el árabe: ¿qué hacemos si un nombre empieza por *al*, como *Al Qaeda*?

Comment: Uf, creo que es más complicado que eso. Pensando en ejemplos, había visto que decimos *la BBC*, pero no *la Aljazeera*; sin embargo, de ahí he llegado a que en España usamos el artículo con todas las las emisoras cuyo nombre está formado por siglas (*la NBC*, *la RAI*) salvo, curiosamente, TVE. Me temo que va a haber demasiadas excepciones y casos especiales como para poder dar reglas claras.

Comment: El uso de artículos en nombres propios extranjeros [no es normativo en castellano](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=internet). A falta de una regla conocida, me parece que lo más seguro (en términos de no cometer error, no de estética) es omitir el artículo en castellano y conservar el nombre completo original. En castellano, sólo se me ocurren ejemplos en que el uso de artículo para un medio viene de que es parte del nombre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existen reglas de conversión de palabras extranjeras al castellano pero no de combinar dos idiomas. La razón la has escrito en tu post ; cada idioma tiene variaciones y habría que hacer reglas para cada idioma. No tiene sentido alguno.

Ejemplo:

Has asumido que sería "Los Rolling Stones" porque sus componentes son hombres, mientras que otra persona podría traducir "Las Rolling Stones" porque stone es piedra y piedra es femenino.

Answer (score 1):

Para el caso de The Rolling Stones no lo veo complicado teniendo en cuenta que el artículo "The" forma parte del nombre de la banda, así que no habría que doblar el artículo y quedaría de esta forma:

> Me gusta escuchar a The Rolling Stones

o

> Me gusta escuchar The Rolling Stones

Sin embargo para el caso del Het Parool se puede usar de las dos formas, añadiendo o no el nuevo artículo, por lo que es correcto decir:

> Me gusta leer el Het Parool

teniendo en cuenta que el artículo "el" se puede estar refiriendo a "el periódico". Así, es como si estuviéramos diciendo:

> Me gusta leer el (periódico) Het Parool

Lo cual no se cumple para el caso de The Rolling Stone ya que no podemos decir:

> Me gusta escuchar los (grupo) The Rolling Stones

o

> Me gusta escuchar los (banda) Rolling Stones

Ninguna de estas dos últimas formas es correcta porque vemos que pierde sentido la oración, pero la última es menos correcta aún porque estamos quitándole parte del nombre a la banda (el artículo "The").

Conclusión: Para cada caso y cada idioma tendríamos que analizar cada uno de estos detalles analizados anteriormente:

- Si el artículo forma parte del nombre original o no, para saber si se puede suprimir o agregar el nuevo en nuestra lengua.
- Si añadiendo el nuevo artículo en español (en este caso) no perdería sentido la oración.
- Entre otros elementos a tener en cuenta que pueden existir.

Comment: This is a really difficult area as it can be hard to know whether the article is really part of the name. According to Wikipedia the name of the group is Rolling Stones so you could say _Me gusta escuchar el Rolling Stones_ with _grupo_ understood to follow

Comment: That's right @mdewey. I never had thought in that way.

Comment: Adriana, veo que eres cubana. ¡Qué bien tener miembros de tantos países! En [esta publicación de Meta](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2484/1674) detallamos respuestas que tienen versiones en distintos idiomas. ¿Te apetece echarle un vistazo para ver si puedes incorporar la versión propia de Cuba? ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Gracias @fedorqui. Sí, soy cubana. Esta respuesta es sólo mi punto de vista, como yo lo veo o entiendo, siendo de Cuba.

Comment: Fantástico, muy amable Adriana. Es muy útil tener la visión de hablantes de distintos países para mejorar esas respuestas. ¡Muchas gracias!