# Use of definite article with names of newspapers

Tags: gramática, artículos

In a previous post fedorqui posed the question
[¿Se debe escribir artículo delante de una palabra extranjera que ya lo contiene en su lengua?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17551/se-debe-escribir-art%C3%ADculo-delante-de-una-palabra-extranjera-que-ya-lo-contiene) which referred to (mostly) newspaper titles from other languages which already contain the definite article. This raised in my mind the question of how we talk about Spanish language (SL) newspapers and magazines.

In some cases the name already contains the definite article so we say

> Leo un artículo en El País
>   Leo un artículo en La Tercera

But it seems that if there is no article in the title we do not add it. For instance the SL Wikipedia refers to the paper simply as *Clarín* without adding "el" before it. So I assume I would say:

> No he leído nunca un artículo en Clarín

I also notice that the sports paper As has a feature which it calls *La chica de As* and not *del As*.

Comment: I believe that's wrong, you should say `no he leído nunca un artículo en el Clarín`. Without the article sounds ugly. As the article is not part of the name, it should be lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the names of the newspapers (and brands in general) happens the same as with every common name, you must not use the article when speaking about them in a general way:

> Yo fumo Ducados.
>
> Yo sólo conduzco Toyotas.
>
> Yo soy lector de ABC.

Nonetheless, you must use an article when speaking about a given unit.

> El ABC de hoy.

In your example, *la chica de As* refers to a girl representing the newspaper as an entity. If it were *la chica del As*, it could be a girl picked for today's newspaper (*la chica del As de hoy*).

But wait, because you can also say *yo soy lector del ABC*, so what's happening here? In fact, this question is similar to the question about whether putting an article before years: *en 2007* or *en el 2007*? Both are valid because the second one is a short version of *en el año 2007*. With the newspaper is the same: *el ABC* is *el periódico ABC*. So you can say *esa noticia la leí en Clarín* and *esa noticia la leí en el [diario] Clarín*.

The trick is, some newspapers names already have an article in the name. So to avoid a cacophony, we suppose the article is already given and do not add another one.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely correct. The trick here is to notice that the names of the newspapers that you mention include the articles (i.e. the article is part of the names, so it is included always).

As a native speaker, this morning "he leído un artículo en **El Pais**, he visto una noticia de **El Mundo**, y me he asustado al ver una imagen en **Público**; sin embargo, la misma imagen no era tan terrible en la portada de **La Razón**. Curiosamente, la imagen ni siquiera aparecía en **ABC**"

Comment: I believe this varies regionally. In my country we say `vi un reportaje en la BBC`, `vi un reportaje en el CNN`.