# ¿Se debe usar la conjunción "u" en lugar de "o" ante números?

Tags: ortografía, conjunciones

Tomemos como ejemplo esta frase:

> ¿Es correcto usar '80 ***o** 80s para referirnos a décadas?

Puesto que "80" empieza por "o", para evitar la cacofonía entiendo que lo correcto sería decir y escribir lo siguiente:

> ¿Es correcto usar '80 **u** 80s para referirnos a décadas?

¿Es esto así, o tiene alguna excepción la norma en cuanto a números?

Y ya que estamos...
¿Qué se haría ante siglas como *OHL*, acrónimos como *OTAN* y palabras como *hoyuelo*?
¿Y ante extranjerismos como *one* que empieza por "o" pero se pronuncia "*uan*" o "*guan*"? Como por ejemplo en: «*la palabra "uno" comparte raiz con otras extranjeras como* "un" *o* "one"».

¿Es la norma puramente fonética, o depende también de la letra siguiente, aunque sea ésta muda?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sí, debe cambiarse la *o* por *u* cuando la sigue un número empezado por *o*.

Del Diccionario panhispánico de dudas en su artículo [*o*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=7wb3ECfmhD6reWjGRa):

> 2. **La conjunción o toma la forma u cuando precede a una palabra que comienza por el sonido `/o/`**: *No sé si la jarra es de latón u hojalata; Tendrá siete u ocho años*. **La misma transformación se da si la conjunción va entre números: *Tendrá 7 u 8 años*.**

En cuanto a la pregunta:

> Y ya que estamos... ¿qué se haría ante siglas como *OHL*, acrónimos como *OTAN* y palabras como *hoyuelo*? ¿Es la norma puramente fonética, o depende también de la letra siguiente, aunque sea ésta muda?

Sí, sería *u hoyuelo* pues la regla habla del sonido, no de la letra y *hoyuelo* fonéticamente empieza por `/o/`.

En cuanto a los acrónimos y las siglas, no encuentro una explicación oficial en el artículo de Fundéu [siglas y acrónimos, claves de redacción](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/siglas-y-acronimos-claves-de-redaccion/). Sin embargo, menciona:

> De acuerdo con la Ortografía de la lengua española, una sigla es un «signo lingüístico formado generalmente con las letras iniciales de cada uno de los términos que integran una expresión compleja» (...)

Dicho lo cual, lo correcto considero que sea considerarla una palabra como cualquier otra a los efectos de las conjunciones, por lo que yo apostaría por decir *u OTAN* y *u OHL*.

Comment: @walen De hecho estaba editando para responder a la parte de la pregunta original que me quedaba pendiente: siglas y haches. Sobre las palabras extranjeras creo que se utilizaría el mismo argumento: la fonética. Sin embargo, sería difícil marcar un límite: el inglés es idioma ampliamente conocido y la pronunciación tiende a saberse; sin embargo, en otros idiomas la confusión puede ser grande. Me recuerda lo debatido en [¿Se debe escribir artículo delante de una palabra extranjera que ya lo contiene en su lengua?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17551/1674).